# Dynamic file name generation in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to upload data to an S3 bucket using a storage integration. My query looks something like that:

```sql
COPY INTO @storage_int/subfolder/name_${date} FROM (SELECT * FROM table1);
```

What I can't figure out is how to declare a variable, such that the expression would evaluate into `storage_int/subfolder/name_2022_13_07`, or what you would achieve using string formatting in Python with `f"name_{date}"`. For date I would want to use the `CURRENT_DATE()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Snowflake Scripting and dynamic SQL:

```
BEGIN
   LET sql := 'COPY INTO @storage_int/subfolder/name_<date> 
               FROM (SELECT * FROM table1);';

   sql := REPLACE(sql, '<date>', TO_VARCHAR(CURRENT_DATE(), 'YYYY_MM_DD'));
   
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (sql);

   RETURN sql;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Following  @Lukasz advice I used the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` approach but I built the query using pipes.

```sql
DECLARE
    sql VARCHAR(100)
BEGIN
    sql := 'COPY INTO @storage_int/subfolder/name_' || TO_VARCHAR(CURRENT_DATE) || 
           ' FROM (SELECT * FROM table1);'
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql;
END;
```

This approach let me build an arbitrary string without having to use `REPLACE` function on each variable I wanted to put in the string.

Comment: Usage of REPLACE was a deliberate choice instead of string concatenation. It enables to show entire query at once and it is workaround for a lack of SQL "printf/string interpolation" equivalent.